# Using Windows 7 32Bit Product Key to Clean Install Windows 10 64Bit?

Tags: windows-10

I would like to know if it's possible to use the windows 7 32bit product key to activate the windows 10 64bit doing a clean installation?

Comment: See this page to possibly recovery the key from the coa sticker even if it is not visible, they scanned the coa sticker then used image software to read the product key not visible to the human eye....http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/308585-recovering-windows-product-key.html

Comment: Another method here used acrylic paint, scroll to last post...http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/software-os/f/3524/t/19362388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 product keys are valid for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

Assuming you have a 32 bit installation of Windows 7 at the moment, you would need to do a *clean install* of a 64-bit Windows 10 installation, using the installation media since the November 1511 build. An earlier build **will not** accept a Windows 7 Product key.

Alternatively, you could clean install Windows 7 64-bit using your product key, and then upgrade to Windows 10 after. Either way, a clean installation will be required if you currently have a 32-bit installation.

Some further reading and tutorial [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/228042/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-windows-10-to-64-bit-windows-10/). You can get an ISO to install from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

Comment: Clean Installing Windows 10 64 Bit from Windows 7 32bit Key that's possible?

Comment: @The_Little_Cousin Yes, as long as you're using the latest ISO from the Microsoft site and not a version before November build 1511.

Comment: I created a USB Boot from the MS Tool Today! Then uses MagicalBean KeyFinder to get my 32Bit windows 7 CD Key should this work fine?

Comment: @The_Little_Cousin If your device has a CoA sticker on it [like this](http://www.techulator.com/attachments/Resources/4217-301120-large.bmp) you should use that key, as the one retrieved by key finders could be a generic OEM one.

Comment: Well if the sticker is partially erased and blur, is they and tool tht can help me get the key?

Comment: @The_Little_Cousin If your machine was built by an OEM it likely uses a bulk key they apply to all machines. You will probably need to interpret the key from your machine correctly, as it may not be the one saved in your machine at the moment.

Comment: so is their any way of proceeding or am stuck and I need to upgrade to Windows 10 32 Bit first then from their carry on?

Comment: @The_Little_Cousin You can't upgrade to Windows 10 64-bit from Windows 10 32-bit. You are somewhat stuck if you can't read your valid product key from the CoA sticker, as I'm suspicious the one you've recovered will be rejected as it's only valid for bulk OEM installations.

Comment: Yea am bit suspicious as well :P Will see how the hell I can manage to make this work!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if you do a clean install and not an update.

By the way, you must directly install the 1511 version of Windows 10 to be able to use directly your Windows 7 Product key.

You can get the iso (depending on your version) directly from : https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench